# How can I create a custom mode in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

According to the [Ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-styles#ionic-modes), there are 2 modes: **ios** and **md**.

How can I add create my own custom mode?

I want to use an Ionic project to create an Electron app. I'd like to set the "core" platform to my own modified version of the Fluent Design.